# Sending json payload to mqtt using jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am new to jmeter .Could someone provide me some idea how I can push a json payload using jmeter to my mqtt .

Added mqtt plugin and able to connect to my mqtt server and there is only option for string ,HexString or RandomString .

[image]

Also want to know the latency ,throughput for each message,any plugin please suggest ,I am using perfmon for cpu ,memory tracking now .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace your `hi this is Chintamani" with your JSON payload like:

```
{"hi":"this is Chintamani"}
```

as [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) is nothing more than a structured string so **String** type should be just fine.

If you're using [xmeter mqtt plugin](https://github.com/xmeter-net/mqtt-jmeter) - it [does measure latency](https://github.com/xmeter-net/mqtt-jmeter/search?q=setlatency)

[image]

Throughput is being measured by JMeter itself and according to [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) it's just a number of requests which JMeter executed for the duration of the test.

You might be interested in [Testing the MQTT Messaging Broker for IoT - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-the-mqtt-messaging-broker-for-iot-a-guide) article which sheds some light on the specifics of the MQTT load testing using JMeter

Comment: thanks a lot ,also I need to export all the load testing performance details into a doc or pdf anything is fine ,is there any plugin for that .